# Copy formatted data from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

i have preformatted table HEAD in range from A4 to O5, and i need to copy it from my Hidden Settings page to a new created one with all formatting ( text aligment, column sizes etc. ).

I do this:

```
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim SheetName As String
    SheetName = TextBox1.Text
    Sheets.Add.Name = SheetName
    Sheets("AdminSettings").Range("A4:O5").Copy
    Sheets(SheetName).Paste
    Sheets("Programma").Select
```

I have found this:

```
    Sheets(SheetName).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

but it fails

This is what i need to see:

[image]

this is what i get:

[image]

**It seems that Text is formatted as needed, but column and row sizes - are not remaining, how to achieve this?**

Comment: Did you try `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`?

Comment: Just tried. Run-time error'1004': PasteSpecial method of worksheet class failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use `.PasteSpecial`, you have to paste into a specific range on a worksheet, so:

```
Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial ...
```

You are attempting to copy column widths and row heights.  In order to paste row heights, the entire row must be copied and pasted.  In order to paste column widths, a second call to `.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths` is required.

So:

```
Sheets("AdminSettings").Range("4:5").Copy
Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
```

should do it.